# Making custom fixed-point depending on integer part of number

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've run to an issue where I need to have different size fractional part of number depending on size of integer.

for example I need a number to be exactly 6 symbols long.

I came to this:

```
let a = 2587.45874;
let integerPart = Math.floor(a).toString().length;
let fixedPoint = 6 - integerPart;

a.toFixed(fixedPoint);
```

That does the job, but I think thats a bit too complicated and there is a more simplified solution, so I'd like to hear your opinions.

so it supposed to be like this.

```
12542.15654 > 12546,1
0.45646578 > 0.45646
12.564644 > 12.5646
135.98745 > 135.987
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think `padEnd` or `padStart` would help you, it fills in the end/start of a string with predefined value:

f.e:

```js
const value = "123.45";

// 7 because of the dot
console.log(value.padEnd(7,"0"));
console.log(value.padStart(7,"0"));
```

Comment: Well that's not exactly what I am looking for, it just adds 0 to specific location. I've edited my case with more details.

Comment: Oh, then I doubt if there is a more pretty solution, yours is quite good I believe